# Properly linking to a javascript library installed with npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I install a JS library with `npm`, say:

```
npm install chartjs
```

It places the required JS file in `./node_modules/chartjs/chart.js`.

Since I want the file to be located in, say, `./public/js/chart.js`, I could just copy and paste it there. But is there a proper way to do that, like linking directly to the file installed by `npm` ?

Thanks in advance for your help. (Yes I'm kind of new to JS...)

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you are using *npm* to manage your dependencies then you would use a bundler (such as [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/), [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/)) to combine them into a browser-friendly file in your distribution directory.

MDN has a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Understanding_client-side_tools/Package_management) which walks through setting up a basic project in Parcel.